# What is the weight at which an aircraft no longer requires a licensed pilot on board in Europe?

Tags: easa-regulations

According to [this](http://www.ubergizmo.com/2011/04/flynano-plane/) (somewhat dubious looking article):

> Since it is so light, the FlyNano falls under the weight of what is considered to be a plane, so in most countries you won't need a flying license to take this baby to the skies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aircraft weight needs to be **70 kg** or less. FlyNano mentioned this on their [FAQs page](http://www.flynano.com/faq.htm) (*my paraphrasing*):

> Do I need a pilot's license to operate FlyNano?
>
> According to the [European Aviation Safety Association regulation](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/;ELX_SESSIONID=vFcfJhvJ1mdjTLgsmf0c1pDYgVWChtskKmQCyrw2Vvn4vNsMG2hG!1622802082?uri=CELEX:32008R0216)
>   ... FlyNano is below the necessary weight of 70kg ... In Finland for
>   example no classification, **no aviation license or medical
>   certification are needed**. But skill is needed. Nevertheless a good
>   understanding of water plane operation, rules and aviation safety is
>   requested. ...

I found that [any aircraft less than 70kg is not affected by EASA regulations](https://www.iaa.ie/index.jsp?p=102&n=387&a=0). But regardless, and emphasized by FlyNano also, pilot skills are required.

Comment: This also says that Amateur/Experimental built aircraft are exempt regardless of weight.

Comment: I found this document that seems to have the full legal code that lists these points. http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/;ELX_SESSIONID=CDMWJhrZLxpHyJ3QRN4v18gvYJpZ1pnGWZdGj91SYZYdsGvvrcGx!1674962396?uri=CELEX:32008R0216

Comment: @LewisGoddard Sweet, gonna build me a Concorde!

Comment: One important thing to note from that FAQ, though is `"FlyNano is below the necessary weight of 70kg, which means that national authorities decide on the classification."` So, no license is required in Finland, but the requirements might not be uniform across the E.U.

Comment: @reirab As I posted further up, these are actually European legislations that exclude it from their licensing. Countries could add their own, but by default, you're all good!

Comment: @LewisGoddard Right, that was my point: while EASA does not regulate such aircraft, individual countries may have their own rules for them, so someone wanting to fly one should still check with their local regulations.